# Display a custom taxonomy in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I have added a new taxonomy called "Vendor" to Woocommerce with the following code:

```
// hook into the init action and call taxonomy when it fires

add_action( 'init', 'create_vendor_taxonomy', 0 );

// create and register vendor taxonomy (hierarchical)

function create_vendor_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Vendors', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Vendor', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Vendors', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Vendors', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Vendor', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Vendor:', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Vendor', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Vendor', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Vendor', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Vendor Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Vendors', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'vendor' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'vendor', array( 'product' ), $args );

}
```

I want to insert this new taxonomy between the Category and Tags labels that appear on a single product page.

I have a child theme and understand that I must create a woocommerce folder in the child and then add to that folder a copy of the woo template files that I must edit.

Can anyone help me?

1. What woo template files must I edit?
2. What code do I need to add to these files to insert my new taxonomy into the product page?

Thanks in advance for any kind assistance.

**UPDATE:** 
Upon further research it would appear that I do not need to edit the Woo template files.

There is a hook available just below the Category and Tags meta on the single product page. That will do the job.

So I can insert the Vendor taxonomy details with the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'insert_vendor_custom_action', 5 );

function insert_vendor_custom_action() {
    global $product;
    if [WHAT DO I NEED HERE?]
    echo [WHAT DO I NEED HERE?];
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To display the post terms from a custom taxonomy terms in meta section of Woocommerce single product page, you don't need to override any Woocommerce template.

Instead you can use the specific dedicated action hook this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'action_product_meta_end' );
function action_product_meta_end() {
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'vendor'; // <== Here set your custom taxonomy

    if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) 
        return; // exit
    
    $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') );

    if ( ! empty($term_ids) ) {
        echo get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Vendor:', 'Vendors:', count( $term_ids ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', ', ', '</span>' );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: Loic.  Thank you very much for your kind assistance. It would seem I posted my update just as you were posting your answer. I assume that I can change the span class "posted_in" to anything I chose and then use that class to style the Vendor: label with CSS?

Comment: @khunmax Yes you can try to change html tag classes as you want or you can add to them additional ones, to style them…This answer code is based on the template `single-product/meta.php` and [**this related functions source code**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_product_tag_list.html#1009-1033) too.

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec could please help me with this please? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/317734/how-to-filter-taxonomy-of-a-custom-post-type-and-display-it-in-the-single-post-t

Comment: @leonardeveloper Sorry I don't answer in WP StackExchange, as plugin questions are off-topic. I only answer some chosen Woocommerce Tagged questions in StackOverFlow

Comment: I vote for this answer.. however, I needed to add a check for a blank array variable returned when no taxonomy records exist.. if (!is_wp_error($term_ids) && !empty($term_ids)) { echo get_the_term_list(...) } Thanks!!

Comment: @MartyMcGee You are right… I have updated my answer (in this case `! is_wp_error($term_ids)` is not required here), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

keeping `string $taxonomy` will cause a php error that can be fixed by removing `string` and keeping the code as `if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )` will resolve the issue