# Display custom taxonomy terms on WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I am figuring out how to display a custom taxonomy on the WooCommerce shop loop.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50863851/1092677), which has pointed me in the right direction. I have modified the code from that answer, to the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_product_meta_end' );
function action_product_meta_end() {
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'keyfeatures'; // <== Here set your custom taxonomy

   if( ! is_taxonomy( $taxonomy ) ) 
       return; // exit
    
    $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') );

    if ( ! empty($term_ids) ) {
        echo get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), 'keyfeatures', '<br /><span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Key Feature:', 'Key Features:', count( $term_ids ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', ', ', '</span>' );
    }
}
```

The part I am stuck on is this line:

```
echo get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), 'keyfeatures', '<br /><span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Feature:', 'Features:', count( $term_ids ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', ', ', '</span>' );
```

I changed was was `Vendor` and `Vendors` (the name of the taxonomy) to `Feature` and `Features`. But I'd actually like to remove this entirely.

I would like to out put the custom taxonomy terms in the following format:

```
Term1 | Term2 | Term3
```

The line above outputs them as:

```
Features: Term1, Term2, Term3
```

I'll also need a `<span></span>` around the output, so I can style it with CSS.

What changes do I make to get the desired output? (Just the taxonomy terms, separated with a pipe `|`, and nothing else?

###Update
In the comments swadhwa suggested I look at [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/), which was exactly what I needed to see.

Based on the info on that page, I changed my line of (output) code to this:

```
echo get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), 'keyfeatures', '<span class="mks_prod_keyfeatures">', ' | ', '</span>' );
```

Yet, oddly, the output from Wordpress was putting the `<span class="mks_prod_keyfeatures"'></span>` into the an `<a ...></a>` from above my taxonomy output. So I also had to change the WC hook from `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title` to `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`. That gave the desired result.

Comment: have you referred to this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/

Comment: @swadhwa Oh great. That looks very helpful. Checking it out now. Thanks.

Comment: if you wanna remove Features,  just leave the third argument blank and replace the third argument from a `,` to `|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your output to be this:

```
Term1 | Term2 | Term3
```

Then this should help:

```
get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), 'keyfeatures', '<span class="posted_in">', '|', '</span>' )
```

where the third argument is the before content, fourth is a separator, and fifth is after content.

Comment: Thanks. I also figure this out, after you left the comment pointing to the docs for this function.  However, the WC hook I was using gave some erratic output. See my update in my question. I resolved that. I'll mark your answer as correct.